# Stack Exchange newsletters including ServerFault sent with Stack Overflow email?

Tags: bug

Emails from all non-StackOverflow stack exchange websites are sent from StackOverflow email. Is this intentional? It does look a bit weird in my Inbox as well because of the "name" of the email.

Example (before the change):

`From: "Stack Exchange" <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
To: 
Reply-To: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
Subject: Server Fault Weekly Newsletter - Friday, January 12, 2018
Date: Fri, 12 Jan 2018 17:23:18 +0000`

After the change

`Date: Fri, 2 Feb 2018 19:18:01 +0000
From: "Stack Overflow" <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>
To: 
Message-ID: <9MkPIhCaSYiCxjVjf6gXsA@ismtpd0001p1iad2.sendgrid.net>
Subject: Server Fault Newsletter - Friday, February 2, 2018`

In addition, ServerFault newsletter now has a default styling instead of the ServerFault styling.

[image: Newsletter style change]

Answer (score 3):

Server Fault is part of the Stack Exchange group of websites, the largest of which is Stack Overflow. It's quite normal for email to be sent from Stack Exchange's general mailing system.

Comment: But it's sent from "StackOverflow" not the other way!

Comment: SO's what the company's called soooo....